# How to create a 100% width select with SelectBoxIt.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some trouble creating a 100% width select box with SelectBoxIt.js

Even when setting the CSS width to 100%, the select box will not fill 100% of the container element.

CSS:

```
.test1, .test2, .test2 .selectboxit, .test2 .selectboxit-options {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select name="test2" class="test2">
  <option value="SelectBoxIt is:">SelectBoxIt is:</option>
  <option value="a jQuery Plugin">a jQuery Plugin</option>
  <option value="a Select Box Replacement">a Select Box Replacement</option>
  <option value="a Stateful UI Widget">a Stateful UI Widget</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Greg Franko helped me solve the issue.

You can see the solution in JSBin.
http://jsbin.com/udapic/1/edit

Basically, you need to disable autoWidth like so:

`$(".test2").selectBoxIt({ autoWidth: false, copyClasses: "container" });`

And then set the width to 100% in your CSS:

`.test1, .test2, .test2 .selectboxit, .test2 .selectboxit-options {
  width: 100%;
}`

Comment: I didn't vote you down. But: This looks like a Q&A post by yourself. Please add at least the relevant code parts `.selectBoxIt({ autoWidth: false });` and the used CSS `width: 100%;` to your answer to make it self-contained.

Answer (score 10):

js

```
$(".mySelect").selectBoxIt({ autoWidth: false });
```

and then css

```
.selectboxit-container {
    width: 100%;
}

    .selectboxit-container .selectboxit {
    width: 100%;
}
```